# Best way to sort and bucketize a list of strings

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hash

**Input**

I have a list of MAC addresses `(AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA)`.

**Objective**

Sort the list, and bucketize them such that mac address sharing the first 8 nibbles falls in one bucket.

**Sample Input**

```
AA:AA:AA:AA:11:11  
AA:AA:AA:BB:15:BA
AA:AA:AA:AA:22:22  
AA:12:12:12:AA:15
AA:AA:AA:BB:11:11
AA:AA:AA:AA:12:12
```

**Sample Output**

```
AA:12:12:12:   
            AA:15
AA:AA:AA:AA:
            11:11  
            12:12
            22:22  
AA:AA:AA:BB:
            11:11
            15:BA
```

**My approach**

```
Container - std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> > bucket  
The map has a custom comparator function which compares 8 nibbles  
Insert 8 nibbles as key:  
    If not already present in map, add entry  
    If already present add, balance 4 nibbles into the value vector
```

Comment: Please show evidence you've tried something, otherwise this seems like a case of you asking others to help you cheat on your homework.

Comment: If I mention the algorithm I am thinking of and ask other ways, question will be closed as saying too many answers. If I just ask the question alone, I am getting down-votes. Not sure what is expected here.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list using [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). I would suggest you consider each pair of hex digits as a single digit for the sorting.

Comment: Can sorting and bucketing be achieved together in radix sort? 8 nibbles will become the bucket?

Comment: @cppcoder if you consider all the buskets at the same time you will have to choose one out of `256^6 = 2^48` This are way too many buckets IMHO

Answer (score 0):

you can make an n(16)-ary tree,(you can see also as a range tree).